# Where clause in Java

Tags: java, class, where-clause

I have a class Player which I load from a database:

```
public class Player{

    int id, score;
    String name;

    public Player(int id, String name, int score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

The class Main has all of them in an `ArrayList<Player> player`.

Is it possible to find a particular instance of that class with something similar to the `where` clause in SQL?
I just need the name if I have the ID.
Example:

```
"SELECT name FROM Player WHERE id = 5";
```

Comment: How are you querying the database at the moment? It's better if you change the query than iterate over all the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can keep your `Players` in a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer,Player> players;
```

and then get the required `Player` with:

```
Player player = players.get(5);
```

Comment: SQL would return a result set with every `Player` whose ID was 5, your solution only returns one `Player`.

Comment: @Jeffrey id's are generally unique in SQL. I tried putting the question in the context. I'm willing to bet id's aren't repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes . One of the way is use the [CollectionUtils.filter()](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) from the Apache Common Collections.
The  "where clause" can be written inside the `evaluate()` of `Predicate`.

Something likes this:

```
CollectionUtils.filter(player, new Predicate() {
            public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
                return (((Player) object).getID() == 5 )
            }
});
```

Then the player list will only contains the Player object whose ID is 5

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your collection of `Player`s and every time you come across one where `player.getID() == 5` you add it to another collection of `Player`s.

E.G.:

```
List<Player> players = ...
List<Player> foundPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Player player : players) {
    if(player.getID() == 5) {
        foundPlayers.add(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems wildly inefficient.

Comment: Really?  Why?  How else do you propose doing it?  Where's your improved solution?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore How is this wildly inefficient? It runs in `O(n)` and finds every `Player` whose ID is 5.

Comment: @Luchian, how is this inefficient? Building a map of the players requires the same iteration over the original list. This is only "inefficient" if the operation is repeated many times, in which case it obviously makes sense to build a map once rather than repeat the list iteration/lookup. But for a single iteration, building a Map and iterating the list to find matches is functionally the same thing.

Comment: If you only query once, it doesn't matter, but if you make hundreds of thousands of queries, iterating through the collection of players every time is kind of inefficient.

Comment: Plus every single search requires a rebuild of a second list (including a full-non-indexed search of the first list).  This is not scalable, and is definitely "wildly inefficient".

Answer (score 1):

Write a Filter class that takes a Collection and returns a Collection:

```
public interface Filter<K, V> { 
    Collection<V> filter(Collection<K> unfiltered, Map parameters);
}
```

Then you can do whatever you like:

```
public class ByIdFilter<Person, String> implements Filter<Person, String> {
    public Collection<String> filter(<Collection<Person> persons, Map parameters) {
        // particulars here.

    }
}
```

Maybe LINQ from .NET would be a good model to investigate and follow.

Comment: I'll bet anyone who's new to a language says the same thing about it until they understand the idiom and how it works.  What's your preference?  Maybe Python is for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a method to return a Player instance based on the ID, like as follows:

```
private Player findPlayerById(int id) {
     for (Player p : player) {
          if (p.getId() == id) return p;
     }
     return null;
}
```